# Summing all the times of a column

Tags: timing

It is possible to add a last row in the table where I can show the sum of values of the last column. I would like to get the total time value...

```
data = {
   {"Caixa Pokémon", DateObject[{2019, 8, 27}], 22.41, 
    TimeObject[{2, 35}]},
   {"Cortador Lindinha", DateObject[{2019, 8, 28}], 3.91, 
    TimeObject[{0, 41}]},
   {"Suporte Principal do Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 01}], 
    12.28, TimeObject[{2, 00}]},
   {"Cortador Woody", DateObject[{2019, 9, 01}], 5.62, 
    TimeObject[{1, 01}]},
   {"Suporte-Trava Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 2.08, 
    TimeObject[{0, 22}]},
   {"Suporte-Tampa Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 1.67, 
    TimeObject[{0, 16}]},
   {"Suporte-Trava Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 2.05, 
    TimeObject[{0, 21}]},
   {"Jogo de Hóquei do João Pedro", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 6.48, 
    TimeObject[{0, 55}]}};
Text@Grid[Prepend[data, {"Projeto", "Data", "Metros", "Tempo"}], 
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
      Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}}, 
  Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}}, Alignment -> {{Center, Center, {Center}}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{10, Full, 5, Full}}, Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], 
  ItemStyle -> 14, Spacings -> {15, .8}]
```

[image]

Comment: can you explain what exactly _sum of the times_ mean?

Comment: are you sure that TimeObject is what you need there? Can you comment on what your last column represents? Is that an absolute time or a time interval? If it's an absolute time (e.g. 11:30am), what do you mean with sum of two absolute times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your aim, I think you shouldn't use a TimeObject as last column of your table, you should use a Quantity, because it looks like you are considering time intervals and not absolute times.

If that's true, TimeObject is probably not the correct choice, as it "represents a time object of standard normalized form" (quote from documentation): this is an absolute time and not a "DeltaT", and summing two absolute times doesn't make much sense (while you can sum an absolute time with a time quantity, as documented).

See example below for using time quantities instead of TimeObjects:

```
toQuant[inp_] := 
 Quantity[MixedMagnitude[inp], MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes"}]]

data = {
   {"Caixa Pokémon", DateObject[{2019, 8, 27}], 22.41, 
    toQuant[{2, 35}]},
   {"Cortador Lindinha", DateObject[{2019, 8, 28}], 3.91, 
    toQuant[{0, 41}]},
   {"Suporte Principal do Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 01}], 
    12.28, toQuant[{2, 00}]},
   {"Cortador Woody", DateObject[{2019, 9, 01}], 5.62, 
    toQuant[{1, 01}]},
   {"Suporte-Trava Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 2.08, 
    toQuant[{0, 22}]},
   {"Suporte-Tampa Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 1.67, 
    toQuant[{0, 16}]},
   {"Suporte-Trava Carretel Maior", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 2.05, 
    toQuant[{0, 21}]},
   {"Jogo de Hóquei do João Pedro", DateObject[{2019, 9, 06}], 6.48, 
    toQuant[{0, 55}]}};

totalTime = 
  UnitConvert[Total[data[[;; , -1]]], 
   MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes"}]]
```

> 8min 11s

**EDIT AUTHOR:**

```
totalMeters = data[[#, 3]] & /@ Range[Length[data]] // Total;
```

And the table (code taken from Alx reply):

```
Text@Grid[
  Append[Prepend[
    data, {"Projeto", "Data", "Metros", "Tempo"}], {"TotalDuration", 
    "", totalMeters, totalTime}], 
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
      Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}, Lighter[Red, .9]}}, 
  Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, 
     Darker[Gray, .6]}}, Alignment -> {{Center, Center, {Center}}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{Full, Full, 10, Full}}, Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], 
  ItemStyle -> 14, Spacings -> {5, .8}]
```

[image]

Of course, if you meant different units (and not hours/minutes), the code can be easily adapted ;)

Comment: I liked your method and just tried to add one more line of code

Comment: Thanks! Obviously you can apply the "meters" unit to the second last column if you need it

Answer (score 2):

Convert `TimeObject`s in column 3 to durations by taking the difference from `TimeObject[{0,0}]` and take to the sum:

```
to = TimeObject[{0, 0}];

durations = data[[All, -1]] - to;
```

> {2.58333h, 41.min, 2.h, 1.01667h, 22.min, 16.min, 21.min, 55.min}

```
totalduration = Total @ durations
```

> 491.min

If needed convert to display in mixed units;

```
totalinmixedunits = UnitConvert[totalduration, MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes"}]
```

> [image]

To combine all steps in a single step, use

```
totalinmixedunits = UnitConvert[Total[data[[All, -1]] - TimeObject[{0, 0}]], 
   MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes"}]]
```

Use `totalinmixedunits` as the last item in the new row:

```
lastRow = {"Total Duration", "", "", totalinmixedunits};

Text @ Grid[Append[Prepend[data, {"Projeto", "Data", "Metros", "Tempo"}], lastRow], 
    Background -> {None, 
       {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}, 
        Lighter[Red, .9]}}, 
    Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, Darker[Gray, .6]}, 
       {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, Darker[Gray, .6]}}, 
    Alignment -> {{Center, Center, {Center}}}, 
    ItemSize -> {{Full, Full, 10, Full}}, Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], 
    ItemStyle -> 14, Spacings -> {5, .8}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can `Dot` the `TimeObject`s with `{60, 1}` and take the sum:

```
Total[data[[All, -1, 1]].{60, 1}]
```

> 491

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[%, "Minutes"], MixedUnit[{"Hours", "Minutes"}]]
```

> 8 h 11 min

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that Mathematica can take difference of two `TimeObject`s but not their sum. So we need to strip `TimeObject` wrapper and sum up all the internal lists. Then we need to convert the resulting list to `{h,m,s}` form and wrap it in `TimeObject` again to get better representation. So the function proposed is this:

```
totalTime={PadRight[#1, 3], PadLeft[#2, 3]} & @@ (QuotientRemainder[#, 60] & /@ 
 Total[First /@ data[[All, -1]]]) // Total // TimeObject
```

And the table:

```
Text@Grid[Append[Prepend[data, {"Projeto", "Data", "Metros", "Tempo"}], {"Total    Duration","", "", totalTime}], 
Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}, Lighter[Red, .9]}}, 
Dividers -> {{Darker[Gray, .6], {Lighter[Gray, .5]}, 
Darker[Gray, .6]}, {Darker[Gray, .6], Darker[Gray, .6], {False}, 
Darker[Gray, .6]}}, Alignment -> {{Center, Center, {Center}}}, 
ItemSize -> {{Full, Full, 10, Full}}, Frame -> Darker[Gray, .6], 
ItemStyle -> 14, Spacings -> {5, .8}]
```

[image]

If one do not need hour (00) it can be easily removed:

```
totalTime={PadRight[#1, 3], PadLeft[#2, 3]} & @@ (QuotientRemainder[#, 60] & /@ 
  Total[First /@ data[[All, -1]]]) // Total // #[[2 ;;]] & // TimeObject
```

Comment: I don't think it's strange: just looking at the documentation of TimeObjects, it looks like TimeObjects are thought as absolute times, not time intervals, e.g., Represent 11:30am: TimeObject[{11, 30}].  Summing absolute times doesn't make much sense: for example, what would be the meaning of 11:30am + 12:30am? On the other hand, difference makes perfect sense, at least from an intuitive point of view :)